# How do you restore scene state if app is terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible to retrieve scene state if an app is terminated by the system / user in SwiftUI?

For example lets say the user had followed a couple of `NavigationLink`s on a `NavigationView` when they closed the app and it was subsequently terminated for whatever reason. Is it possible to restart the app the next time it loads in the same state so the user is on the view they left with the same view hierarchy intact?

If anyone could give me any advice on if this is possible or not / point me in the direction of some resources that would be great.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to store your state in the `UserDefaults` every time it is changed.

Comment: You need `@SceneStorage`, just find examples & articles about it.

Comment: @koen - I can store my state in UserDefaults - but how can I store the view / previous view hierachy?

Comment: @Asperi - thanks, I'm currenlty looking into this.

Comment: You could maintain a hierarchy tree and store that. But maybe that is what `@SceneStorage` does, but I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @koen - interesting, I'll have a play. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Asperi - I'm having trouble seeing how this could be used to restore a view + hierachy - I can see how it could be used to store variable in each scene and restore them but not automatically get the user back to the view they were on.

Comment: @swift--help did you figure it out?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't worked it out completly yet. As soon as I do I'll post here.